# file_get_contents gives error in codeigniter

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter

```
$scope.formatfilename = response.fileformat[0].FileName;
```

// it contains filename = abcd

```
 $filename1 ='{{formatfilename}}'; // now I have taken into phpvariable
 $siteaddr = "http://localhost:8080/demoproject/document/".$filename1.".html";
echo file_get_contents($siteaddressAPI);
```

it gives me Failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
if I assign full url static to $siteaddressAPI then it gives the result.

how to solve in codeigniter ??

Comment: try with urlencode - `$siteaddr = urlencode($siteaddr);`

Comment: You define and set `$siteaddr` but then try to read the file at `$siteaddressAPI`.  Where did `$siteaddressAPI` come from?

Comment: I have read that file using file_get_contents() method. The problem is when I pass variable name to $siteaddr it will give bad request but When I pass directly url to file_get_contents() method it shows the output

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:**
change in php.ini

```
allow_url_fopen = On
```

**Option 2:** use cURL
You might want to try using curl to retrieve the data instead of file_get_contents. curl has better support for error handling:

```
 $filename1 ='{{formatfilename}}'; // now I have taken into phpvariable
 $siteaddr = "http://localhost:8080/demoproject/document/".$filename1.".html";
// make request
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $siteaddr); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    $output = curl_exec($ch);   

    // convert response
    $output = json_decode($output);

    // handle error; error output
    if(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) !== 200) {

      var_dump($output);
    }

    curl_close($ch);
```

**Working Example**

```
<?php

$siteaddr = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=YOUR_API_KEY";
// make request
$ch = curl_init();
// Disable SSL verification
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// Will return the response, if false it print the response
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// Set the url
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $siteaddr);
// Execute
$output = curl_exec($ch);

// convert response
$output = json_decode($output);

// handle error; error output
if (curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) !== 200) {
    var_dump($output);
}

curl_close($ch);
echo "<pre>", print_r($output), "</pre>";
die();
?>
```

**Output**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [error_message] => The provided API key is invalid.
    [results] => Array
        (
        )

    [status] => REQUEST_DENIED
)
```

Comment: It doesn't print anything.

Comment: have you tried `print_r($output);` after `curl_close($ch);` ?

Comment: **1st** check your file can be reach by simple url or not. for an example if you put `http://localhost:8080/demoproject/document/my_page.html` it should be reach and show some data on your browser. ............

**2nd** If your data in file you are calling not have json data then remove `$output = json_decode($output);` from cURL and simply echo your output like `echo $output;`

Comment: Hi Parag, yes I reach that file from url browser. when I pass to static URL to $siteaddr variable that time it shows the file output. but When I append $filename1 into URL that time it gives bool(false).

Comment: @AnilMhaske I have updated the code, by the way to finding bug purpose try one time with static file name instead of `$filename1 ='{{formatfilename}}';` this use `$filename1 ='yourfile_name`

Comment: When I use static url that time it show html file. The problem is when I pass $filename1 variable. $filename1 variable contains file path also.